# Autocompletar jTextField en Java

Tags: java

En una **aplicación** de tipo `Java Swing`, he añadido un elemento llamado `jTextField`. Estoy utilizando **Netbeans** 8.0.2 en un **Windows 8.1.**

Vayamos a lo relevante:

Tengo un campo de tipo `jTextField` en el cual quiero ingresar el nombre de una ciudad. El campo `jTextField` se llama `textfield_ciudad`.

¿Por qué me da error si tengo implementada/agregada la **librería JAR** correspondiente? **¿Qué "import" debo añadir para detectar la clase?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me detecta la clase **TextAutoCompleter**. Todas las líneas me salen incorrectas debido a que no detecta esa clase.

**Código:**

```
    TextAutoCompleter textAutoAcompleter = new TextAutoCompleter(textfield_ciudad);
    textAutoCompleter.addItem("PUEBLO 1");
    textAutoCompleter.addItem("PUEBLO 7");
    textAutoCompleter.addItem("PUEBLO 12");
    textAutoCompleter.addItem("PUEBLO 45");
    textAutoCompleter.addItem("PUEBLO 11231");
    textAutoCompleter.addItem("PUEBLO 1 AAA");
    textAutoCompleter.addItem("PUEBLO 1555");
    textAutoCompleter.addItem("PUEBLO 1 PUEBLO 1");
    textAutoCompleter.addItem("PUEBLO 1222");
    textAutoCompleter.addItem("PUEBLO 4144");
    textAutoCompleter.addItem("PUEBLO 12");
```

**Error:**

```
Cannot find symbol - symbol: variable textAutoCompleter
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu código no compila, asegurate de ponerle imports y tener siempre un [mcve]

Comment: @RuslanLópez Sólo puse el código problemático debido a que el resto del código no es relevante para el problema, pero si es mejor lo añado.

Comment: Como no es una librería estándard ni popular muy pocos posiblemente sepamos de qué estás halando.

Comment: Ahh y por ende tampoco entendemos a qué te refieres cuando dices que salen incorrectas

Comment: @RuslanLópez Que no compila..., en resumen: al no detectar la clase entonces las asignaciones no son correctas.

Comment: Nada, no sé que librería usas, que versión de librería es, como la estás agregando a tu CLASSPATH, cómo declaraste tus variables, que sistema de construcción estás usando, que sistema operativo tienes, que versión de Java tienes, que error te sale y qué te debería de salir en su lugar, si estás haciendo consulta de tu base de datos, etc

Comment: @RuslanLópez ¿de verdad hace falta saber cómo declaré la variable o el campo jTextField, el cual aclaré que se llama textfield_ciudad, o hace falta indicar si uso Windows 7 o 8.1 o 10?

Comment: Efectivamente, como no has puesto de dóde sacaste la librería no sabemos si usa llamadas nativas de sistema, como no pusiste como declaras tu textField puede ser que no lo hayas inicializado y en muchos casos sucede que el error solo pasa en determinado sistema operativo, por ello es ideal saber tu entorno para saber si lo tienes bien configurado.}

Comment: @RuslanLópez Actualizado.

Comment: todo parece indicar un problema de scope. No podría decirte más hasta  no tener más detalles

Comment: @RuslanLópez Dije todos los detalles de mi problema. Creo que es que tengo el .jar incorrecto o no es el indicado.

Comment: Como verás te faltaron los imports, no dijiste si marca error en le resaltado de sintaxis, ni en que línea y si está dentro de un método eso que pusiste o de dónde sacaste la librería. Asumo que tratas de llamarlo sin haberle puesto la visibilidad adecuada. Recuerda que no leemos mentes y parte del mcve es tener todo lo necesario para reproducir tu problema

Comment: @RuslanLópez No he encontrado ningún ejemplo con el import adecuado al .jar agregado, por eso no me detecta la clase. Esa es mi duda, a ver si podéis resolverme qué import debo añadir para que detecte la clase.

Comment: de dónde sacaste el jar?

Comment: Intenta con este import: `import com.mxrck.autocompleter.TextAutoCompleter`

Comment: @RuslanLópez Me dice "paquete no existe".

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107550/discussion-between-ruslan-lopez-and-omaza1990).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algunas veces no basta con solo dejar el *jar* en el directorio de librerias, si obtuviste el `error: package com.mxrck.autocompleter does not exist` entonces lo que tienes que hacer es descomprimir el *AutoCompleter.jar* en el *CLASSPATH* manualmente para que quede desplegado el directorio `com\mxrck\autocompleter` que en efecto es el paquete que el compilador no encuentra.

*Con el código que posteaste veo este ejemplo*:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y cómo se descomprime un .jar? descomprimir el AutoCompleter.jar en el CLASSPATH manualmente para que quede desplegado el directorio com\mxrck\autocompleter

Comment: Se descomprime como cualquier *rar* o *zip*, o puedes, por *CMD*, ubicar el directorio donde está el *jar* y luego usas el comando `jar xvf AutoCompleter.jar`

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer y me sigue sin compilar, o sin detectar el archivo .jar. Ya lo he descomprimido en la carpeta /dist/lib pero sigue sin detectarme la clase.

Comment: /dist/lib no es el *classpath*, fijate donde se crean los *.class* de tu app, justo en la raiz de ese directorio va ese com/mxrck...., ahí es donde el compilador busca los compilados. Trataré de editar mi respuesta ;)

Comment: Tomé un momento para instalar Netbeans, agregue la librería con la opción '*add JAR/Folder*' en las propiedades del proyecto y también corrió sin problemas, uhm? vuelve a importar debidamente ese *jar* o consigue otra versión del mismo...

Comment: Añadi una ilustración para que veas mi error.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107559/discussion-between-johnnytb-and-omaza1990).